# Buildozer building pygame error. Fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found. sdl2.c

Tags: pygame, sdl-2, buildozer

When I try to build an APK file using buildozer I keep getting this error.

src_c/_sdl2/sdl2.c:2112:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found.

I made sure that my pygame, buildozer, and sld2 are update to the latest versions. And I am using python version 3.12.1 .

Any ideas?